# How to install via source code / Installing in Ubuntu (PPA)

Tags: lubuntu, ppa

Is there some general way of installing a software in Ubuntu (or Lubuntu) when the software provider says:

> PPA repository for Ubuntu right now is outdated. We strongly recommend you that install via source code

I could not find any guidance on the provider's site

http://turpial.org.ve/downloads/

Comment: Ok so I actually downloaded the source code (tar.gz file) and read "README.rst" - where instructions on installing can be found.

Installation
------------

Turpial is available on most popular Linux distributions, so you should be able  to install it using your favorite package manager (aptitude, apt-get, pacman, yum). Please visit http://turpial.org.ve/downloads for more information.

To install Turpial from sources you should go to source folder and 
run (as superuser):

    # python setup.py install

or using `sudo`::

    $ sudo python setup.py install

Comment: You are making your life far too difficult ;-) See the answer and use the middle part (`sudo apt-get install turpial`).

Comment: Ok, I was blindsided :) But why did the provider not put this info in the Ubuntu section? Anyways, 'sudo apt-get install turpial' does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could not find any guidance on the provider's site

All the info you need is there; you just missed a vital part of that page. See the last bit of my answer.

---

Regarding source install: download the `tar` file on that page you linked to and read the `install.txt` or `readme`. It will have command line instructions on how to install. Not the easiest method though and if you get uncompiled code you also need to compile (ie. configure/make) it. If you are lucky they did that for you and installation is just a copy/paste.

From the "tar":

> To install Turpial from sources you should go to source folder and run (as superuser):
>
> ```
> # python setup.py install
> ```
>
> or using sudo::
>
> ```
> $ sudo python setup.py install
> ```

---

**Normal install is possible from the repositories**

Turpial is in the repositories.  So ...

```
sudo apt-get install turpial
```

will install turpial version 3.0 when using Ubuntu 15.04.

---

**Method for getting the newest version**

But the easiest method listed on that page that will work for Ubuntu is PIP:

> Installing via PIP
>
> ```
> pip install turpial
> ```

Generally pip will not be installed on your system and if you do not have pip installed ...

```
 sudo apt-get install pip
```

Currently this will install version 3.0 so it should be the same as the one from our repositories. In case there is a new version and 15.04 is not told there is an update you can get the newer version like that.

Comment: You can also do: `sudo apt-get install turpial`.

Comment: @chili555 check :)

Comment: or `sudo checkinstall setup.py install` ;)